# Funcion y Objeto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Hola soy nuevo con JS y me puse a hace una calculadora solo con un una caja de texto y un boton. Para eso quiero bloquear las letras en la caja de texto, asi que pense en como obtener el keyCode de las teclas pero no sabia como y googleando encontre las lineas comentadas con asterisco y no entiendo porque funciona.

Se que al evento keydown se asigna el valor que retorna la funcion, mis dudas son:

Porque la funcion recibe un parametro si nunca le envie uno?
Porque se ejecuta la funcion cuando occurre el evento sin detectarlo con un addEventListener?
Y porque no me funciona cuando uso getElementsByName para asignar la caja de texto a tecla?

no pregunte en la pag donde encontre la funcion porque el post es de hace mucho y el objetivo del codigo era otra cosa, basicamente solo copie la idea

```
function validarTecla(evObject){ /////*****
    var e = evObject.keyCode;
    if(e<=90 && e>=65){
        return false;
    }
    if(e == 192){return false;}
}

var tecla = document.getElementById("cajaCalculo");
tecla.onkeydown = validarTecla;/////*******
```

Answer (score 2):

Voy a intentar arrojar algo de luz sobre tus dudas.

> *Se que al evento keydown se asigna el valor que retorna la función, mis dudas son:*

No es del todo cierto, en realidad ahí, le estás asignando la referencia a la función.

---

> *Porque la funcion recibe un parametro si nunca le envie uno?*

Fíjate que de hecho ni siquiera la estás ejecutando tu, por eso recibe un parámetro que tu no envías. En realidad lo envía el propio evento.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event

---

> *Porque se ejecuta la funcion cuando occurre el evento sin detectarlo con un addEventListener?*

Tu estás asignando el listener al setear el valor

```js
tecla.onkeydown = validarTecla
```

---

> *Y porque no me funciona cuando uso getElementsByName para asignar la caja de texto a tecla?*

No te funciona porque `getElementsByName` no devuelve un item sino una lista de ellos.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Espero que esto aclare algo tus dudas.